# Getting partial Json response

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting a server side json response to load my menu, I tried twice and it gave this error message (the Error parsing data org.json.JSONException).

the reason for that is I'm getting the response partially, in both attempts i got different responses as shown in the images. i think I'm not getting the complete json response, getting only partial response. what should I do to get the complete response.

this is my code

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    String path = null;
    String response = null;
    HashMap<String, String> request = null;
    JSONObject requestJson = null;
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    StringEntity requestString = null;
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;

    // get the email and password


    try {
        path = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        new URL(path);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        // set the API request
        request = new HashMap<String, String>();
        request.put(new String("CetegoryCode"), "P");
        request.entrySet().iterator();

        // Store locations in JSON
        requestJson = new JSONObject(request);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
        requestString = new StringEntity(requestJson.toString());

        // sets the post request as the resulting string
        httpPost.setEntity(requestString);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // Handles the response
        responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

        responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return responseJson;

}
```

this is the image

[image]

Comment: response which u are getting from your api is returning JSONObject or JsonArray ?

Comment: JsonArray >> response starts like this,  Value [{"ItemCode":"ABCD","IsMayoBaseAvailable":false,

Comment: are you getting response in responseJson = new JSONObject(response); ?

Comment: yes, for the (response)..

Comment: Can you show your whole response or url from where you are getting actual response?

Comment: @GrIsHu Web server is sending the complete json response array but when I'm accessing it, I'm getting it partially. is there a limit for a response?

Comment: @JohnDavid No there is no limit for response. Try out my answerl.

Comment: @JohnDavid the way u hve implemented is not proper way to call API ... pls check the updated answer .. even you should create the instance of JsonArray if response starts with array and jsonobject if its start with json object

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code to parse and get JSON response:

```
public static JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        json = convertStreamToString(stream);

        stream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
```

Use `getJSONFromUrl` method as below in your code:

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    String path = null;
    String response = null;
    HashMap<String, String> request = null;
    try {
        responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
        responseJson =getJSONFromUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?CetegoryCode=p");

     }catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
 return responseJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your response is returning JsonArray thn need to set tht response string jsonarray. create instance of jsonarray and fill it up with the response.

if its normal get ws thn you can append parameters in url like query string

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                // Append parameters with values eg ?CetegoryCode=p
                String path = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?CetegoryCode=p";
                URL url = new URL(path);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();

                // Get the server response

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "");
                }

                Content = sb.toString();
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(Content);
                if (jArray != null)
                    Log.e("Data", "" + jArray.length());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Error = ex.getMessage();
            } finally {
                try {

                    reader.close();
                }

                catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }

            /*****************************************************/
            return null;
        }
```